# finding numeric elements in an alphanumeric array read from a file and write them to a new file

Tags: java, file, arraylist

So what my objective is, is to read a text file that is an array with integers and strings then do some calculations with some of the numbers, then put the original data along with the new calculated data into a new text file. But right now I'm just stuck where I can't seem to pick the numbers out of the file and put them into an ArrayList, unless I'm going about this all wrong. Thank you.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class LAB02 {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    Scanner fileStockIn = new Scanner(new FileReader("Lab02Input.txt"));
    PrintWriter reportFile = new PrintWriter("Lab02Report.txt");



    ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();

    while(fileStockIn.hasNext())    //while loop to stay in loop while there are more records
    {//begin while      
        double price = input.nextDouble();
        double shares = input.nextDouble();
        double dividend = input.nextDouble();
        String ticker = input.next();

         Double record = new Double(price, shares, dividend);
            list.add(record);


    }//end while


    fileStockIn.close( );
    reportFile.close( );        

  }

}
```

The input of the text file i'm reading from (bullet points added to make easier to read):

- 42.87 23.33 2.10 EXC
- 12.00 83.33 0.17 ATVI
- 28.15 35.00 0.80 MSFT
- 42.98 23.26 0.65 CVS
- 33.64 29.72 2.20 TXN
- 55.51 18.01 2.00 NVS
- 16.00 62.50 0.40 SPLS
- 19.81 50.47 0.24 CSCO
- 30.09 33.23 1.76 T
- 39.29 25.45 0.60 DIS
- 18.65 53.00 0.29 SNE
- 50.21 19.21 0.72 AXP
- 102.69 9.74 1.44 NIK

Comment: what happens? is an exception thrown? more info please

Comment: Why did you name your class `Double`, which is already a Java class?

Comment: If intention is to read text file, you should just use `fileStockIn`. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);` does not seem to be useful here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Named it double because nothing else was working and saw somewhere online something similar so thought i'd try.

Comment: Since java is a strict language you should be able to use predefined functions that find the integers in the array then store them into a temporary array (double for decimal calcs), perform your calculations then write to a new file.

Comment: @nhouser9 It currently doesn't work at all because when i ran it before it just was blank so this was me trying to fix int then not knowing where to go

Comment: You are reading from System.in, so it is waiting for you to type in the input, rather than reading from the file.

Comment: You only need one scanner object to scan file for the numeric array elements.

Comment: Change all your `input.nextInt()`, `input.nextDouble()` and `input.next()` to `fileStockIn.nextInt()`, ` fileStockIn.nextDouble(()` and `fileStockIn.next()`.

Comment: Also, you're not writing to `reportFile` at any point.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Ok so i've changed that part, but now i'm getting an error for my arraylist which is just "Double cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Also we need to know the context of the text file? Is it an actual array or a list of alphanumeric elements aka strings and integers? Reason I ask this is because we need to determine if we are reading nextLine or iterating through array. Ok I see yes David has you on the right track.

Comment: @Damian What do you think the line `Double record = new Double(price, shares, dividend)` is doing?

Comment: @Damien before you perform any calculations you don't even think about using a function Double(args[]) to perform calcs. Populate array of double, iterate through array then perform calcs at each iteration and add to new temp array. Once youre done you can iterate through temp array and output to new file at each iteration.

Comment: @yardpenalty ok i added it in now, hope that helps.

Comment: @DavidChoweller I was hoping for it to create a list of of them so i could display it easier on another file, but now that it's brought to my attention i think it could be dealt with better.

Comment: @Damian Instead of that line with `Double record = ...` what you should do is what is suggested in one of the answers to your question.  Define a class to store price, shares and dividend.  Now say you named that class `Record`.  Then you would do `Record newRecord = new Record(price,shares,dividend)`, assuming that you defined a constructor that took `price`, `shares` and `dividend` as arguments and set the appropriate member variables in your `Record` object.

Comment: After creating this object  `newRecord`, you would then add this object to your `ArrayList<Record> list` by doing `list.add(newRecord);`

Comment: @DavidChoweller First, thank you for the supports/feedback it's helped me a lot. But i did what persistence suggested and everything worked until i got to the `Calculation calculation = new Calculation(price, shares, dividend);` which then gave me an error of "No enclosing instance of type LAB02 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type LAB02 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of LAB02)."

Comment: @Damian Move the `Calculation` class to a new java file called `Calculation.java` and make the class public.  The message you're getting is because you probably defined `Calculation` as an inner class within your existing '`LAB02` class.  There are other ways of getting around it while keeping your class an inner class, but what I suggested is simplest.

Comment: @Damian Actually, you could also keep the `Calculation` class in your existing file, but make it a private class that is outside the `LAB02` class.  I think that is what the 1st answer is suggesting you do.

Comment: @DavidChoweller I thought i had the calculation class outside the LAB02, but i guess not. And currently there are no errors and it runs only when i tried to test it and did `System.out.print(calculations);` just gave me the word "calculations" and a bunch of gibberish after, which i think it needs to be de-serialized but i could be wrong.

Comment: That's because you haven't defined a `toString`method for `calculations`.  The default value printed is the name of the object and its memory address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are trying to have instantiate a `Double` type with a constructor with 3 parameters. Refer the documentation here of how a Double works.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

What you are trying to do is- you need a custom class which holds the three properties like this:

```
 private class Calculation  {
    int price;
    double shares;
    double dividend;

    //getters and setters here
    //constructor
    public Calculation (int price, double shares, double dividend) {
       this.price=price;
       this.shares = shares;
       this.dividend = dividend;
    }
   }
```

And then in your main class

```
     List<Calculation> calculations = new ArrayList<Calculation>();
     while(fileStockIn.hasNext())      {
     //begin while      
        int price = input.nextInt();
        double shares = input.nextDouble();
        double dividend = input.nextDouble();
        String ticker = input.next();

        Calculation calculation = new Calculation(price, shares, dividend);
        calculations.add(calculation);
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify it for you just use something like this:

```
ArrayList<Int> ilist = new ArrayList<Int>();
ArrayList<Double> dlist = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> dlist2 = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<String> slist = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Double> results = new ArrayList<Double>();

while(fileStockIn.hasNext())      {
    ilist.add(input.nextInt());
    dlist.add(input.nextDouble());
    dlist2.add(input.nextDouble());
     slist.add(input.next());
}
```

Now you can use `.get(index)` with for loops to perform calcs

```
//just an example
double total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < dlist.size() i++){
     total += dlist.get(i);
     results.add(dlist.get(i)/dlist2.get(i));
}
```